# Cross-compile from Ubuntu x64 for Raspberry Pi (0, 1, 2, 3) - Not simple code

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, arm, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3

I can't understand how to cross-compile complex source code for Raspberry Pi (so, ARM) from Ubuntu x64. I would compile [libretro-picodrive](https://github.com/libretro/picodrive) for exercise in order to understand how it works with complex code.

On Raspberry Pi the compilation ends without any error.

Please follow these steps.

1.
In ~ directory:

```
mkdir cross-compile
```

2.
Download and extract "tools-master.zip" downloaded from
https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools

in `~/cross-compile` folder

3.
Move in cross-compile folder, then create some folders with:

```
cd cross-compile
mkdir sysroot
mkdir src
```

4.
Power on Raspberry Pi with Rasbpian, then from Ubuntu execute this command in order to copy lib and usr folders from Raspbian to Ubuntu:

```
rsync -rl --delete-after --safe-links pi@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/{lib,usr} $HOME/cross-compile/sysroot
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the Raspberry Pi IP

4.
Add this line at the end of bashrc, so:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

then add this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/cross-compile/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin
```

5.
Run this to reload new PATH:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

6.
Verify the compiler with this command (no error reported):

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v
```

7.
Try to compile source code:

```
cd ~/cross-compile/src/
git clone https://github.com/libretro/picodrive.git
cd picodrive
git submodule update --init
./configure
```

At this point I received the warning:

> please install libpng (libpng-dev)

but I don't understand how to point to sysroot folder. libpng-dev is installed on Raspbian, so it is present in the usr or lib folders previously copied from Raspberry Pi.

How can I point to the right path (sysroot that contains usr and lib folders from Raspbian) when I launch ./configure?

Where compiler are searching for libpng-dev? I ask this because libpng-dev is installed in Ubuntu, so it is strange that it doesn't found it without any pointing to sysroot folder (at least it must found the library in Ubuntu).

As I said before, on Raspberry Pi the compilation ends without any error.

Could you please help me?

Many thanks

Comment: From personal experience. I have to ask... do you really need to do this? It's not trivial, and more of a headache than building on the RPi directly.

Comment: I want to understand the process for general approach, furthermore compiling software on Raspberry Pi take many hours, sometimes 2 days